# Desktop application with file with environment variable

Tags: environment-variables, autostart

## Context

- XFCE4

## Issue

Trying to run a software with a bunch of environment's variables stored into a file named `prod.env`, directly from autostart.

Here is the content of the `.desktop` file stored at `/home/user/.config/autostart/player.desktop` :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=blablabla
Comment=
Path=/appli/player/
Exec=/bin/bash /appli/player/run.sh start
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

According to documentation, there is no field related to this feature.

Have you a trick that allow to run a program with an environment variables file, using autostart ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure that `/appli/player/run.sh` is executable and has an appropriate shebang line, so that it can be run directly (without `/bin/bash`). Then change the `Exec` line to

```
Exec=/bin/sh -c '. path/to/prod.env && /appli/player/run.sh start'
```

This will source the `prod.env` file, making its contents available in the environment in which `/appli/player/run.sh start` is executed.

You can replace `/bin/sh` with `/bin/bash` if you prefer, but `sh` is a lighter shell.